# How can I change this script to kick user by user id?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have this script for kicking users. How can I change that script so I can kick user by user id?

**Script:**

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = "$";
client.on('message', function(message) {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) { return } 
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
if(command === "kick") {

let member = message.mentions.members.first();
let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
if (member) { // add this
  member.kick(reason);
  client.channels.cache.get('737341022782357566').send("User <@" + member.id + 
  "> with id " + member.id + " has been kicked by <@" + message.author.id + 
  "> with reason " + reason)  
} else {
  message.reply("invalid parameters for $kick")
}
message.delete();
}
})
client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the member by ID:

```js
const Member = message.guild.members.cache.get('MemberId')
if (!Member) return console.log(`Invalid member.`);
```

And then kick them:

```js
Member.kick("Reason").catch(error => {
    console.log(`Couldn't kick ${Member.user.tag}.`);
})
```